# glob - filter - numeric string in folder name

Tags: php

What pattern should I use for glob function to filter only folders that contain numeric string.

this will show only folders with a single digit:

```
glob('/path/to/files/[0-9]')
```

What about folders with multiple digits or when is_numeric is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function filterFiles($path, $flag="", $ext="", $regex_pattern="") {
    if ($ext) $ext=".$ext";
    if ($flag=="files") $files=array_filter(glob("$path/*$ext"), "is_file");
    else if ($flag=="dirs") $files=array_filter(glob("$path/*$ext"), "is_dir");
    else $files=glob("$path/*$ext");
    if ($regex_pattern) foreach($files as $i=>$file) {
        if(!preg_match($regex_pattern, basename($file))){
            unset($files[$i]);
        }
    }
    $result=array_values($files);
    return $files;
}



$revPaths=filterFiles($path,"","","/^\d+$/");
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with `glob`, although messy:

```
glob('/path/to/files/*{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}*',GLOB_BRACE);
```

Instead, combine some functions:

```
array_filter(glob("/path/to/files/*",GLOB_ONLYDIR),function($a) {return preg_match("/\d/",basename($a));}));
```

Comment: The glob syntax won't work (it would match anything containing a digit). IMO your second proposition is the best solution.

Comment: second option is using anonymous func, it's only for php>=5.3

Comment: @Kolink shouldn't the regular expression be `\d+` or `\d*` and not just `\d`?

Answer (score -1):

You're going to want to add the `GLOB_ONLYDIR` flag:

You need to narrow it down to a list containing numbers and letters or just numbers, then filter out the folders that contain letters.

```
$files = glob("[0-9]*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$final_list = [];
foreach($files as $file){
    if(preg_match("/\d+/", basename($file))){
        $final_list[] = $file;
    }
}
print_r($final_list);
```

Comment: Since when did glob support regex components?

Comment: @Kolink http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#88250 I know that guy from phpfreaks.com and he is a very reliable sourece.

Comment: it returns such dirs as "1", "123", "123fg". What if I don't need "123fg"?